# Не срабатывает json success. Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json

День добрый. Столкнулся с json. Не силен тут, Пересмотрел не раз код, пробовал по-разному, прописывал без переменных, без обработки. Данные серверу отправляет. Метод обрабатывает правильно и `$json['total']` - верное значение имеет.
Но `success: function(data)` - не работает. Сделал проверку на `$.ajaxSetup` - `Requested JSON parse failed.`
что не так - не могу понять (

```
public function like(){     

  if($_POST['track_id']) {  
        $json = array();                
        $liked = $this->model->like($_POST['track_id']);
        $res = $this->model->count_like($_POST['track_id']);
        $json['total'] = (int)$res[0]['count_like'];
        echo json_encode($json);
  } 
}

function addLike(track_id) { 
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/tracks/like',  
    data: 'track_id=' + track_id,
    dataType : "json", 
    success: function (data) { 
            alert("1");       
    }           
}); 
}
```

Comment: {"total":14}  ответ в файрбаге верный. Status 200 OK 69ms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно проверить, есть ли вывод чего-то ещё после Вашей функции. Просто переделать последнюю строчку запроса на

```
exit(json_encode($json));
```

Если после этого у Вас ошибка - что-то выводится перед exit, нужно рыться в коде. Это самый очевидный вариант.

Comment: success заработал )

Comment: тогда не понимаю, echo лишнее, но это же не логично

Answer (score 0):

Чудес не бывает - если возникает ошибка `Requested JSON parse failed` - значит, сервер и правда отдал что-то, что не является корректным json.

Смотрели ли вы результат запроса в инструментах разработчика в браузере? Первое пришедшее мне на ум предположение - PHP выдал какое-нибудь предупреждение, которое и нарушило валидность ответа.